# How to assert a specific text in cypress

Tags: cypress

Please see the below code.
I am trying to assert value 2 but my code is not working.

[image]

Comment: cy.get('#_evidon_message').then((txt)=>
  {
    const text=txt.text()
    cy.log(text)

  })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do something like this:

```js
cy.get('#_evidon_message').should('contain.text', '2')
```

Comment: Its not working since 2 is in bold attribute

Comment: When you log the inner text what do you get ?

Comment: I am not getting any text

Comment: Use this `cy.get('#_evidon_message').then((txt)=> { cy.log(text) })` and then tell me what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, it isn't clear if you want to check the entire text within the `div` or just for the number before `partners`.

If you only want to validate there is a `2` within the entire string, then:

```js
cy.get('#_evidon_message')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('include.text', '2')
```

You can use also use regex on the string as well.

```js
cy.get('#_evidon_message')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => {
     const regexMatcher = /(\d+) months with (?<numPartners>(\d+)) partners/i
     const numPartners = text.match(regexMatcher)?.group?.numPartners
     expect(numPartners).to.eq(2)
  })
```

Comment: The element is enclosed in iframe
I am using 
const getIframeBody = () => {
    // get the iframe > document > body
    // and retry until the body element is not empty
    return cy
    .get(iframe_desktop)
    .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
    // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
    // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
    // https://on.cypress.io/wrap
    .then(cy.wrap)
  }
 
  getIframeBody().find(evidon_msg).invoke('text').should('include.text','2')

Answer (score 0):

The bold tags `<b>` are interfering with your text evaluation. It's actually HTML inside

```js
cy.get('#_evidon_message').then($el => { 
  const html = $el.html()
  console.log(html)         // yields same as screenshot
})
```

To access the inner `<b>` use additional commands, for example

```js
cy.get('#_evidon_message')
  .find('b')
  .eq(2)
  .should('contain', '2')
```